# "Trace" no (VBA/Excel), como pego o nome de uma subrotina?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, procedure

Como pego o nome de uma subrotina (VBA/Excel) dentro dela mesma para usar em um código do tipo "Trace"? (**ver código básico no bloco ATUALIZAÇÃO *após o código de exemplo***)

A ideia é usar algo como o "ME.Name", que pega o nome do projeto.

Por exemplo, o ideal seria algo como:

```
Private Sub Rotina()

    Trace(???.Name) 'Captura o nome da subrotina como argumento do Trace
    ...
    ...

End Sub


Public Sub Trace(ByVal NomeDaSubRotina As String)

     if TraceAtivo Then

      MsgBox "Estou em " & NomeDaSubRotina 

     End If

    'Pode ser feito também com ListBox (ver código na atualização abaixo)  

End Sub
```

**SOLICITAÇÄO**

Por favor, encontrei várias soluçöes para a questão, mas não tenho conhecimento suficiente em VBA para testá-las. Alguėm pode apontar uma dessas soluções? Segue o link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945321/how-to-get-the-procedure-or-function-name-at-runtime

Grato

**COMPLEMENTO: Resultado da pesquisa!**

Por meio deste "link", fiz alguns testes com os códigos do "site" e fiz o mesmo com outros "sites" dentro deste contexto.

O resultado que cheguei em várias tentativas diferentes é que sempre surge uma mensagem mais ou menos assim:

**"Não é seguro usar esta função"**

Portanto, **"É POSSÍVEL CAPTURAR O NOME DA SUBROTINA DENTRO DELA MESMA, MAS É PRECISO TER UM CERTO TIPO DE PERMISSÃO!!!"**

Pesquisando sobre a mensagem verifiquei que há explicações de como fazer isso, porém, não entendi direito como fazer. Não indico os links no momento, pois fiz as pesquisas fora de casa e precisaria fazer o levantamento onde encontrei, MAS  imaginei que teria tempo no momento para pegar os links e resumir o que cada um continha, e não deu.

**PERGUNTA:**

Quais as consequências e/ou riscos de alterar o nível padrão de segurança e, se decidir por alterar, como proceder? Não entendi muito bem e não quis arriscar sem ter conhecimento de causa. Alguém sabe sobre isso?

Grato

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

O código abaixo funciona como um "Trace" e dinamicamente, sendo muito interessante ver o Listbox apresentar a sequência das subrotinas acionadas a cada ação (em bloco, do início ao final das operações daquela ação).

Ela mostra pelo MsgBox e/ou acrescenta linhas ao Listbox com o "Nome" da subrotina onde "Msg" esteja (coloco na primeira linha de cada subrotina).

Conforme a opção: 1, 2 ou 3 em uma célula no Excel algumas subrotinas ou todas são mostradas, pois, quando dou a outra opção de um número inteiro positivo (em outra célula no Excel), somente uma ou algumas subrotinas indicadas com este mesmo número são mostradas, ou todas, se a opção for -1.

Só falta pegar o nome de cada subrotina automaticamente dentro dela mesma para não ter de digitar seu nome dentro de cada uma.

```
Public Sub Msg(ByRef MsgTexto As String, ByRef MsgTipo As Integer)

' Msg - PARAMETROS: Digitar na planilha nas células:
' MsgOuListbox  e  MsgTipo os valores dos parâmetros.
'
‘ A célula MsgIndice inicia com 0 quando o formulário é acionado, 
‘ e guarda o índice para inserir cada nova linha ao Listbox
'
' MsgOuListbox: 0=Não mostra, 1=Mostra MsgBox  2=Preenche ListBox  3=Ambos
'
' MsgTipo: Indica se mostra MsgBox e/ou acrescenta linha ao ListBox de cada 
' subrotina conforme o número indicado na chamada dentro de cada rotina:
' 0 = não mostra
' 1 ... n = Faz só para o código indicado (um número apenas, pode ser
'        individual de uma subrotina ou um grupo delas com este mesmo número)
' -1 = faz para todas as subrotinas
'
' O listbox foi nomeado como ListBoxMsg1

' Se uma das células tem 0 não faz
If Range("MsgOuListbox").Value = 0 Or Range("MsgTipo").Value = 0 Then Exit Sub

' se tipo 2 ou 3 mostra MsgBox com o nome enviado da rotina
If Range("MsgOuListbox").Value = 2 Or Range("MsgOuListbox").Value = 3 Then

 ' se o número do tipo enviado é o mesmo do parâmetro ou se escolheu -1,    
 ' acrescenta linha ao Listbox
 If MsgTipo = Range("MsgTipo").Value Or Range("MsgTipo").Value = -1 Then

  ListBoxMsg1.AddItem MsgTexto, Range("MsgIndice").Value

  Range("MsgIndice").Value = Range("MsgIndice").Value + 1

 End If

End If

' se tipo 1 ou 3 pode mostrar o nome enviado com MsgBox  
If Range("MsgOuListbox").Value = 1 Or Range("MsgOuListbox").Value = 3 Then

 ' se o número do tipo enviado é o mesmo do parâmetro ou se escolheu -1,
 ' mostra MsgBox
 If MsgTipo = Range("MsgTipo").Value Or Range("MsgTipo").Value = -1 Then

  MsgBox MsgTexto

 End If

End If

End Sub
```

Dentro de cada subrotina coloco no início:

**Msg "NomeDaRotina", 1**

em outra:

**Msg "OutraSubRotina", 12**

Se colocar nas células da planilha **MsgOuListbox = 2**  e  **MsgTipo = 12** , somente o nome das subrotinas que indiquei o número **12** aparecerão dinamicamente no Listbox (se acionadas durante a execução), neste exemplo **"OutraSubRotina" será mostrada** e **"NomeDaRotina" não será mostrada**.

Comment: Por que não `MsgBox("Rotina")` ?

Comment: É que um dos motivos é ver a sequência que o programa está seguindo no meio de tantas rotinas, e daria nuito trabalho escrever rotina a rotina o nome de cada uma, quero por um comando comum em cada uma que quero ver, a princípio é isso.

Comment: Outro motivo é que estou pondo opções de ver por MsgBox e/ou Listbox, e com parâmetros, ver somente algumas ou todas

Comment: Veja o código que inclui acima!

Comment: Não entendo muito de VBA e Excel, apenas trabalho com uma linguagem estilo basic também e fiquei curioso para saber o seu intuito. Espero que encontre a ajuda que precisa aqui. Além disso, encontrei essa resposta no SO em inglês que talvez ajude, se você conseguir entender: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20864585/1796236

Comment: Obrigado pela busca, Pablo, mas apesar de similar, pois ele quer fazer o mesmo para os argumentos passados, não apresenta a solução que desejo.

Comment: Tem uma pergunta similar no SOen (só que lá é VBA no Access - não deve dar muita diferença), com algumas respostas. Pode ser que alguma te ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792134/get-name-of-current-vba-function

Comment: Ok, inclusive a referência ao código citado anteriormente está lá. Preciso analisar melhor, pois pode ser que tenha como funcionar, mas creio que somente alguém com mais experiência possa verificar isso de fato. Grato

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A alguns anos atras eu tive a curiosidade de fazer um tratamento de erro desses assim que saiu o pacote .Net, até hoje espero alguma função quer permita isso, a resposta é que não é possível pegar, não simplesmente do jeito que você quer.

Eu achei [esse código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31461821/3517631), vale uma tentativa:

```js
ErrorHandler:
   Dim procName As String
   procName = Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.ProcOfLine(Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.TopLine, 0)
   MyErrorHandler err, Me.Name, getUserID(), procName
   Resume Exithere
```

Ele diz que funciona na versão 2010...

O que eu sugiro você fazer é uma classe de Tracer, onde você pode construí-la no inicio do método passando para ela o nome do método.

Essa classe seria responsável por fazer o log, ela pode escrever onde você achar melhor, e ainda conversar com outras classes.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Vou colocar um exemplo de como pode criar uma classe de Trace.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é um projeto teste, fiz agora...

Código do form:

```js
Public Class Form1

    Private meuTrace As Trace

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        meuTrace = New Trace(ListBox1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        meuTrace.logar("Cliquei no botão 1")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        meuTrace.logar("Cliquei no botão 2")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        meuTrace.logar("Cliquei no botão 3")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Essa é a classe Trace:

```js
Public Class Trace

    Private _lista As ListBox
    Public Sub New(lista As ListBox)

        _lista = lista

    End Sub

    Public Sub logar(log As String)

        _lista.Items.Add(log)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Ao clicar nos botões ele vai escrevendo no list.

Com essa solução você pode criar uma instancia de Trace passando o seu list para ela e usar essa instancia em qualquer lugar, sem ter a dependência de ter que ver a List.

Deu para visualizar mais ou menos como pode ser feito?

Comment: Se você achou o código, seria justo [citar a fonte](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31461821/2896619). :)

Comment: Nossa Senhora, ta aberto aqui para colocar a fonte lá, não lembre de fazer o.O ... Vou editar

Comment: Sem problemas. Pela edição, ganhou meu +1. :)

Comment: Ricardo, ainda não sei fazer uma Classe, coloquei o código dentro de uma subrotina e deu erro dizendo que "o acesso de programação ao projeto do VB não é confiável" (Erro 1004). Tem outra forma de fazer? Coloquei desta forma: Dim procName As String
   procName = Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.ProcOfLine(Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.TopLine, 0)
   MsgBox procName

Comment: Vou montar uma classe para tentar fazer o que você quer, só que meu VB está MUITO enferrujado, terminando eu coloco na resposta.

Comment: @Leo da uma olhada na atualização da resposta, acho que pode ser uma boa solução

Comment: Oi Ricardo, muito bom, vou aprender trabalhar com Classes. Similarmente, o que faço é: logo abaixo da criação da subrotina, eu copio o nome dela para o meu comando Msg.  Fica assim: Msg "ComboBox1_Change" ,3 (o três é o identificador para visualizar só o que quero, só aparecerá esta informação se minha célula no Excel "MsgTipo" estiver com 1, 2 ou 3 (MsgBox, ListBox ou Ambos respectivamente). Valeu!.  Muito obrigado.